# XML-based xls file won't open correctly

Tags: excel, xls

I generated an xls-file in the [XML format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_Spreadsheet_example). The approach used to work for me. Now all of a sudden I cannot open the file neither in Excel, Numbers of google sheets. The content of the file `test.xls` is simple as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Release Date</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Price</Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error you get? You will get [a warning message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/948615/error-opening-file-the-file-format-differs-from-the-format-that-the-fi) because of course the `XML` file is not really a `*.xls` file. But if you click `Yes` button, the file should be opened in Excel.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't recall getting that error before. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Either you do what is described in the link in my first comment or you create **really** a Excel file instead of to foist Excel a `XML` file.

Comment: Thanks I will will go with a CSV instead then :-)

Comment: Hm, although `CSV` is the smallest common multiple for data exchange, it is mostly not the best solution. Explicitly for `Excel` there are better solutions by using libraries which provides possibilities for real creating `*.xls` and/or `*.xlsx` files in correct format. Such libraries currently are avaliable for most of the programming languages.